# navigator.mediaDevices not available in Angular 8 app production build

Tags: angular, production-environment, navigator, mediadevices

I want to use `navigator.mediaDevices` in my app, and in development build all works, I have access to this object. When I build a production, and upload app to server, navigator have no object like mediaDevices. I can't find any information about it anywhere.

I use angular 8.

I create a basic test application, after that create an production build and I uploaded app to my server. In local host i have access to `navigator.mediaDevices` in prod version on my server it is `undefined`

my production app: http://modecode.pl

What could be wrong ?

Comment: PROBLEM RESOLVED, I uploaded app production build on server without https, ```navigator.mediaDevices``` is only available with https

Comment: Yeah, I had the same problem with my react video chatting project. Although localhost was `http` it worked (`window.isSecureContext` returned true) but when deployed to a `http` server, it did not work because `window.isSecureContext` returned false.